# System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type_.Only primitive and...this context

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, exception

This seems to be the error cropping up when the following linq query is compiled. i had read a few similar issues but all emphasized on using .Any() function instead of .Contains().. However despite that, there seems to be an error compiling the statement and an exception is logged.

This is the statement:-

```
int result=0;
result = (from u in objContext.CLG_challengeMaster
          where u.appId == applicationId
          && objContext.CLG_taskDetail.Any(e => e.challengeId == u.id)
          && !objContext.CLG_challengeDetail.Any(e => e.challengeId == u.id && (e.userId == null && e.groupId == null && e.appGroupId == null && e.roleId == null))
          select u).Count();
```

This is the error logs:

```
Message: System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'DataAccess.Entities.Models.CLG_taskDetail'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConstantTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConstantExpression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
   at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NewArrayInitTranslator.<>c__DisplayClass0.<TypedTranslate>b__1(Expression e)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.EnumerableValidator`3.Validate(IEnumerable`1 argument, String argumentName, Int32 expectedElementCount, Boolean allowEmpty, Func`3 map, Func`2 collect, Func`3 deriveName)
   at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.EnumerableValidator`3.Validate().........
```

Can anyone plz help.

Comment: Finally had to break it up and reconstruct it :(

Answer (score 0):

in this line if `&& objContext.CLG_taskDetail.Any(e => e.challengeId == u.id)` CLG_taskDetail could be null then change the line to be:

```
&& (objContext.CLG_taskDetail.Any() && objContext.CLG_taskDetail.Where(e => e.challengeId == u.id))
```

Otherwise change it to using a 'Where' clause

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. Compilation error saying : Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error CS0019 Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'IQueryable<CLG_taskDetail>'

Comment: You could try the following as I think the problem above is that you haven't joined the tables.    `objContext.CLG_challengeMaster.Where(u=>u.appId == applicationId && u.CLG_taskDetail.Any(e=> e.ChallengeId == u.id) && !u.CLG_challengeDetail.Any(f=>f.challengeid == u.id &&
f.userId == null && f.groupId == null && f.appGroupId == null && f.roleId == null)).count();` dont think you need the select on this one